qmail: Edit Subject line before forwarding
I would like to annotate/tag some mail subjects in qmail, before forwarding them to the destination.
With the .qmail file I managed so far to analyze and edit the incoming mail and to forward the mail. What I have failed so far is to forward the edited mail.
# Edit subject line
| sed 's/Subject: /Subject: FOO/g'
# Forward to other alias
bar

Is this even possible with only qmail or do I need another tool for that?
